# Ajax --> asp.Net error 500 (internal server error)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a ASP.NET WebMethod from a javascript function but every time I try it returns me the error 500

Javascript:

```
function enviarParaASP() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'GoogleMapsGeolocation.aspx/SalvaCoordenadas',
            type: "POST",
            data: "{'coord' : " + coordenadaASalvar + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "script",
            //beforeSend: function () {
            //    alert("Start!!! ");
            //},
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("OK ");
            },
            failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
        });
    }
```

ASP.NET:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void SalvaCoordenadas(object coord)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

UPDATING...

I found the solution, was just to add "STATIC" to the webmethod like this:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void SalvaCoordenadas(object coord)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

thanks for the help, now I want to know how to debugg the server :P

Comment: put a breakpoint in your server method and see why it is getting  an exception ?

Comment: What is coordenadaASalvar?  A string or a javascript object?

Comment: coordenadaASalvar I think it's an object cause I get a coordinate from google Maps API